# Auto-adding new item - Angular UI query

Tags: angularjs

I'm adding a 'new stories' feature to a website for authors to contribute work to. The function below allows stories to be created and added to the author's profile but doesn't auto-add them to a list (ie I have to refresh the browser for this to work. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this (I've tried changing state back to 'authorprofile' but that didn't work).

```
self.addStory = function() {
    var authorId = tokenService.getAuthor()._id;
    console.log(authorId);
    var data = {
      story: self.currentStory,
      authorId: authorId
    }
    Story.save(data, function(story) {
      console.log("saving: " + story);
      Story.put(data, function(story){
       console.log("story added");
      })
      // auto-add new stories here
      $state.go('authorprofile');
    })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list of stories is stored in a 'stories' variable on the scope:

```
// auto-add new stories here
$scope.stories.push(data);
```

Comment: Thanks fikkatra, I haven't quite got it yet but will have a play around with $scope

Answer (score 0):

Add new story into the array using in the success function using push method.

```
  Story.save(data, function(story) {
      //Add stories to the array
      $scope.stories.push(story);
      Story.put(data, function(story){
        console.log("story added");
      })
      // auto-add new stories here
      $state.go('authorprofile');
})
```